# Correct way to create a User on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an activity for Sign up and Login with Firebase

I have a User class like this

```
public class User {
    private final String mProviderId;
    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPhoneNumber;
    private final String mName;
    private final Uri mPhotoUri;
}
```

When a user signs up for a new account I am doing this

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(et_email.getText().toString(), et_pass.getText().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        //Save User to db
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setmEmail(et_email.getText().toString());
                        user.setmName(et_fullname.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(et_pass.getText().toString());

                        //Use email to key
                        users.child(user.getEmail())
                                .setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                //
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

So the primary_key for each user is the email address

I wonder is there a way to use the push() method in Firebase to create a User (auto generate primary_key) and get the key that Firebase provide for each User and store it in attribute "mProviderId"?, Is this the right way the create a User in Firebase?

Thanks for reading.

**Update date 3/22/2018 - think I found the answer**

After a few days of research and coding I found that the correct way to create a User is to use the UID (unique identifier) which Firebase auto generates for you. And store it in the Database along with the User's information (UID as key, User's information as value. This way is recommended by sir **@Doug Stevenson**.

You can do something like this:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // Get User Firebase id
                                String uid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();

                                // Create a User
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setUserProvideId(uid);
                                user.setUserName(name);
                                user.setUserPassword(password);

                                // Put the User to the FirebaseDatabase with User's information. Use "uid" as a Key and user object as Value.
                                databaseReference.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user);
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks to everyone for answering my question.

Comment: you want to get the push key?

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of code.  It's far better to copy the relevant code into your question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: yes but is that a correct way? If that key is the primary_key then the email can be the same for any User?

Comment: @DougStevenson i will notice that in the feauture.

Comment: You don't want to wait for the future - you can edit your question today to include the code instead of the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

It's conventional to use the uid (unique id) of the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) to identify the location in the database where their information is stored.  The uid is, by definition, unique.

```
String uid = authResult.getUser().getUid();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use the uid instead of an email address to store user data.  The email address may change over time, but the uid will be the same forever.  This is the advice in the documentation, especially regarding security rules, where you can use the uid to easily implement per-user protection for their data.  This is the right way to do it.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: @DougStevenson There is an [online course](https://in.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009/) for creating a [shopping list](https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus) made by Udacity together with Firebase engineers, where they explicitly are not using the `uid`, they are using as a unique identifier an `encodeUserEmail`. Are they teaching us wrong?

Comment: I don't know that course, but I can tell you that using an email address as a database key is not the best option.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you please help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380561/uid-or-email-address-as-a-database-key-in-firebase/49380771)?

Comment: Back when this "Firebase Essentials" course was made, there was no way to link accounts. To allow users to sign in with different providers and *still access the same shopping lists*, it was decided to use the email address as the primary identifier for a user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This the answer that I was looking for. Next time I will write a comment and not post a new question. Thank you!

Comment: thanks to @Doug Stevenson I think your way is the most suitable way to create a User. I have updated your answer below my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get push key from in this way.

```
String providerId = users.push().getKey();
users.setProviderId(providerId);
users.child(user.getEmail())
     .set(user)...
```

Note: Push key is generated by firebase it is guranted to be unique.

if you are using firebase auth then `auth.getUser().getUid();` is also a better option to indicate unique user.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use firebase key because is genarate unique there for i am always used that key for id in table.

```
    String id=mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
    User user = new User(id,name);
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(id).setValue(user); // you can also used id as a child node.
```